# Grant non-workgroup/non-domain users access to TFS team project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, virtual-machine

I have a test instance of TFS 2010 running on a Virtual PC 2007/Windows Server 2008 virtual machine.  I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. Allow host computer/user to have network access to TFS Server running on the guest virtual machine.
2. Add host computer/user to have access to a TFS team project (do we HAVE to use Windows Authentication?).  Again I at least want to let the host computer have access.
3. Have this user connect to the TFS Server via TFS Explorer or TFS Web Client

I need to test a Custom TFS Policy that I created to ensure that it works with remote connections.  A TEST environment does not exist where all computers are on the same domain, etc.  This is my only option right now.  Please help!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Team Foundation Clients in a Domain and Team Foundation Server in a Workgroup**

Local user accounts must be created on the Team Foundation server for all users requiring access to the server. In order to avoid users having to type a user name and password every time that a Team Foundation client must connect to Team Foundation Server, these local user accounts should use the same user name and password as the domain user names. For example, if the Team Foundation client user's domain credentials are domainname\user1 and the local user account on the Team Foundation Server is servername\user1 with same password, the user will not be prompted for credentials when connecting to Team Foundation Server. If they do not match, the user will be prompted for alternative credentials for Team Foundation Server that must match a local user account on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?

You can run TFS in a workgroup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the article that answered my question!